# JavaScript Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is my code below..

```
onRowSelection(event, selectedRule) {
 if(event.node && this.props.selectedRule.id !== null){
     if ( event.node.selected && !this.props.selectedRule || 
         event.node.data.id !== this.props.selectedRule.id) {
         this.props.getRule(event.node.data.id);
         this.setSelectedRow(event.node.data.id)
     }
 }
}
```

I'm receiving an error when i select the row.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Comment: can you add a complete code for your problem, probably a js fiddle link??

Comment: your event.node.data or this.props.selectedRule is null

Comment: The meaning of this error message is  that `this.props.selectedRule` is `null`

Comment: this is a react application and using ag grid, its a lots of codes :/

Comment: Without seeing the full code, I'm assuming you are saying either `event.node.data` or `this.props.selectedRule`is undefined. You could try using lodash `result()` to check if variable is set. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#result

Comment: not working here is full code https://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/eRQYyr

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
 onRowSelection(event, selectedRule) {
     // add checking whether this.props.selectedRule is null or not
     if(event.node && this.props.selectedRule !== null && this.props.selectedRule.id !== null){
         if ( event.node.selected && !this.props.selectedRule || 
             event.node.data.id !== this.props.selectedRule.id) {
             this.props.getRule(event.node.data.id);
             this.setSelectedRow(event.node.data.id)
         }
     }
}
```

Even though this will bypass your error, this wont solve your problem, You need to check why `this.props.selectedRule` coming `null` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`onRowSelection(event, selectedRule)`
`selectedRule` isn't used as it is within the body of your function.
My suggestion (based on the few line code you posted) is to use `selectedRule` where you're using `this.props.selectedRule`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

i write the if condition like this

```
onRowSelection(event) {

    if(event.node && event.node.data){
        if ( event.node.selected && !this.props.selectedRule){
            this.props.getRule(event.node.data.id);
            this.setSelectedRow(event.node.data.id)
        }
        if(this.props.selectedRule){
            if ( event.node.data.id !== this.props.selectedRule.id) {
                this.props.getRule(event.node.data.id);
                this.setSelectedRow(event.node.data.id)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

it seems working now.